# How to change the font property of a tab control without changing the font of its child controls in C#?

Tags: c#, tabcontrol

I want to change the font of a tab control because I want the text in the tab page headers to look bigger. But when I change the font property of a tab control in the Designer (I'm using MS VStudio 2010), the font of its child controls change as well (such as labels and treeview) which I don't intend to do. I just want to change the tab pages' header's font.

edit:
i thought of changing the font property (if there is) of the child controls of the tab control in code by looping through the child controls. would there be any problem with this idea?

Comment: Change the font of the TabPages.  It is risky though, your UI won't rescale properly on a machine with a different video DPI setting.  Test that.

Comment: @HansPassant oh! thanks! :) i don't know how it happened, but the last time i checked, the individual tab pages don't have a font properties. thanks lot! btw, what do you mean by:

your UI won't rescale properly on a machine with a different video DPI setting?

please send me a message about it.

Answer (score 2):

`Font` property in most of the `Win-Forms` control like `Label` is defined as explained below.

```
    The Font property is an ambient property. An ambient property is a control 
property that, if not set, is retrieved from the parent control. For example, a 
    Button will have the same BackColor as its parent Form by default
```

If you want to specify some font at parent level which you don't want to be inherited by child you will have to manually assign child controls some other font