# Changing a tabcontrol's Font changes the size of the content

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I am creating a program that's for use with touchscreens. Everything has to be quite big for usability.

At some point I realized some controls (groupbox with flowpanel inside which contains buttons) had to move inside a tabcontrol to make better use of the resolution we have. Everything went fine until I changed the font size of the tabcontrol's headers. When I change the header font size to a bigger font size (20) all the content grows too. With the content I mean everything. Everything the tabcontrol contains grows along with the header font size. I really don't know what to do here. Is this a bug or what's going on?

I have also tried to change the font size in code, with the same result.

Is there anyone who had the same experience? Or anyone who can reproduce this problem?

SxMT

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892490/how-to-change-the-font-property-of-a-tab-control-without-changing-the-font-of-it

Comment: This answer suggests to set a font size for the children, which is already done, so doesn't solve the problem. EVERYTHING is resized, not just fonts, that wouldn't be much of a problem.

Comment: I'm sorry I have to get back on that. The User Control font size wasn't set, but all the items in the User Control did. So when I change the font size of the User Control, this affects only the size of the User Control in this case. Strange behavior, but well it's fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TabControl -> UserControl -> GroupBox

The problem was that when I changed the font size of the TabControl the font size for all children changed. I had changed the font size for the group box manually but that didn't solve the problem. I had to change font size of the User Control itself instead of the content of the User Control so that it didn't resize.

This is quite confusing because the User Control didn't contain any text directly. Changing the font size of the User Control affects the font size of the children, changing the font size of the children directly didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Your tab control is probably scaling because of font change. [See this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.autoscalemode.aspx)